# avahi-daemon repeatedly registers/withdraws address record causing network failures

Tags: networking, ethernet, avahi

I am using Ubuntu 15.10 using an Ethernet connection to my cable model router. I have not customized the network set up in any way after installing Ubuntu. I've noticed that after about 12 to 24 hours after booting up, Ubuntu starts to drop internet connections. Usually I notice this after webpages fail to load images or CSS files. When this happens I notice that the `/var/syslog` is filled with entries like this:

```
Jan  8 05:26:40 46lbs avahi-daemon[730]: Registering new address record for 2605:e000:850e:8800:d9cb:5166:bac1:61d2 on eth0.*.
Jan  8 05:26:40 46lbs avahi-daemon[730]: Withdrawing address record for 2605:e000:850e:8800:d9cb:5166:bac1:61d2 on eth0.
Jan  8 05:26:43 46lbs avahi-daemon[730]: Registering new address record for 2605:e000:850e:8800:d9cb:5166:bac1:61d2 on eth0.*.
Jan  8 05:26:43 46lbs avahi-daemon[730]: Withdrawing address record for 2605:e000:850e:8800:d9cb:5166:bac1:61d2 on eth0.
Jan  8 05:26:46 46lbs avahi-daemon[730]: Registering new address record for 2605:e000:850e:8800:d9cb:5166:bac1:61d2 on eth0.*.
Jan  8 05:26:46 46lbs avahi-daemon[730]: Withdrawing address record for 2605:e000:850e:8800:d9cb:5166:bac1:61d2 on eth0.
Jan  8 05:26:49 46lbs avahi-daemon[730]: Registering new address record for 2605:e000:850e:8800:d9cb:5166:bac1:61d2 on eth0.*.
Jan  8 05:26:49 46lbs avahi-daemon[730]: Withdrawing address record for 2605:e000:850e:8800:d9cb:5166:bac1:61d2 on eth0.
Jan  8 05:26:52 46lbs avahi-daemon[730]: Registering new address record for 2605:e000:850e:8800:d9cb:5166:bac1:61d2 on eth0.*.
Jan  8 05:26:52 46lbs avahi-daemon[730]: Withdrawing address record for 2605:e000:850e:8800:d9cb:5166:bac1:61d2 on eth0.
```

Usually I can recover normal internet use by disconnecting the wired connection using the networking icon in the Ubuntu toolbar and then reconnecting. However, this is troublesome. I would like to keep the avahi-daemon for the purposes of discovery. Does anyone know how to stop this behavior? For the record, here is the output of my `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:62:66:7c:ea:35  
      inet addr:192.168.0.4  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: 2605:e000:850e:8800:8729:2a19:e7c8:5738/128 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::a62:66ff:fe7c:ea35/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4638380 errors:0 dropped:9 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2164811 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:5378789738 (5.3 GB)  TX bytes:231746518 (231.7 MB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:fb200000-fb220000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:40049332 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:40049332 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:2898153546 (2.8 GB)  TX bytes:2898153546 (2.8 GB)
```

Comment: I'm getting this on 14.04LTS

Comment: Mine seems to have been a weird conflict with an alias I made. YMMV

Comment: https://github.com/lathiat/avahi/issues/41

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found your question when searching for the answer. I also found [this question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/714917/host-name-conflict-with-avahi-daemon-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts):

> If your DNS server that this server uses has a .local domain then avahi will fail to work. See http://avahi.org/wiki/AvahiAndUnicastDotLocal for more info on this.

When I removed my .local domain from my DNS server the problem went away. Hopefully you have the same success.

Comment: I'm having the same problem in ubuntu 17.04, avahi is always registering and withdrawing one adress. Unfortunately, in `/etc/avahi` I can not find any information with .local. Could you further specify the solution? The avahi documentation is currently down.

Comment: I had to change the local domain name I was using from 'something.local' to 'myregistereddomain.com'. The the problem went away. Not a solution that everyone can employ, so if it's not possible, and you find another solution post it up and share it.

Answer (score 0):

One comment points to https://github.com/lathiat/avahi/issues/41, where the issue is explained:

> When ipv6.ip6-privacy 2 (enabled, prefer temporary IP) is set, eventually preferred_lft reaches 0 seconds and that address becomes deprecated at which point avahi-daemon goes crazy and starts to flood the journal every three seconds. Fully 80% of the journal is full of these messages.

Until this is fixed a workaround is to just drop these log messages. For *rsyslog* writing

```
if $programname == "avahi-daemon" and
    ($msg contains "Registering new address record for" or
     $msg contains "Withdrawing address record for") then {
  stop
}
```

to `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-avahi-rsyslog-b41.conf` and restarting the daemon does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've seen these messages by iPv6. I've set `use-ipv4=yes` and `use-ipv6=no` in the `avahi-daemon.conf`, because I just need avahi/zeroconf just in my local network. But still getting these withdraw and assign messages in 1 minutes interval.

Now I find: I have to set `publish-aaaa-on-ipv4=no` in the `avahi-daemon.conf` section `[publish]` to prevent using ipv6 - and the messages are gone.